# Electrical feed back on charger

Tags: battery, battery-drain, battery-charger

Do chargers like the one used to charge a car battery draw power when it is still connected to the battery but not to the wall outlet?
or still connected to the wall but the power is off?
[image]

Comment: Anecdotal:  My kids have a 12v Power Wheels jeep with a "smart charger".  If you leave the smart charger hooked to the battery but not plugged in, it will drain the battery.  Now, and old-school charger like the one in the picture?  I'm not sure, but its at least possible with some chargers.

Comment: to find out for sure use a multi-meter to measure the current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the unit. When a charger is still connected to the DC battery side, but not the AC wall plug, it ideally should not be doing anything at all. If you see something obvious like LED or other lights still on, then yes you might have some kind of parasitic drain from the charger. As mentioned, the only way to be sure is test with an amp meter and see if there is any current draw when the charger is hooked up but not charging.

In practice though, if your batteries are going flat when the charger is not connected to AC power, it may just be that the cells are damaged and can't hold a charge anymore. In this case it wouldn't really have anything to do with the charger other than coincidence.